# How does this verb interaction work?

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns

In the sentence, how do verbs interact?

> 時を表す同じ語を前後に置いて、それを強調する意を表す。

I understand `時を表す同じ語を前後に置いて` as `place identical time representing words at the front and rear` but I don't really know if this is correct. Is it a similar to the following `それを強調する意を表す`?

How does it work?

Comment: What is this explanation about in the first place? Is this about an English phrase pattern (eg "day by day") or something different?

Comment: I assume this is from the definition of という from kotobank or weblio?

Comment: Ah, so this is an explanation of 今日という今日は!

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm assuming that this is either from the [weblio entry](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86) or the [kotobank entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86-579242) of という, which are basically identical. You are understanding the first part of the sentence correctly. However, the second clause after the comma is not a restatement of the first clause.

> それを強調する意を表す 
> expresses emphasis of that.

"That", here refers to the time phrase/時を表す語. Because the clause before ends in the て-form (置いて), you can interpret it as "by the means of" or simply as the action that comes before it.

> 時を表す同じ語を前後に置いて、それを強調する意を表す。
> By placing a time phrase before and after (という), you are able to emphasize it.

If you are not familiar with using て conjunctively, this [imabi article](https://www.imabi.net/theparticleteiii.htm) does a pretty good job explaining it.